# What is the exact criteria for an inout port, when sometimes inout and output ports can be interchangeably used in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, asic

In the below module, **ideally cnt, width & start should be inout port,** instead of output port.

**But I tried with those ports as output ports** and still I am able to run it without any error. So can inout and output ports be used interchangeably in Verilog?

If no, then what is the exact criteria, where inout port must be used (output port can't be used in that case)?

```
module (clk, rst, cnt, start, width, signal);
  input clk, rst, signal;
  output reg [11:0] cnt, width;
  output reg start;

  always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
  begin
    if(~rst)
    begin
      cnt <= 0;
      start = 0;
      width <= 'h271;
    end
    else
    begin
      if(signal)
      begin

        width <= (start) ? width : 'h271;
        start = 1;
      end
      cnt <= (start) ? (cnt + 1) : cnt;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Note - I know, that with inout ports, I need to modify the code, as inout ports can't be of reg type. But I am here asking about just type of ports only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port direction is basically advisory in Verilog, and this hasn't changed in SystemVerilog. This is a historical isue, and is related to how Verilog XL (the first Verilog simulator) did port collapsing; basically, everything is an inout. when the '95 LRM was written this existing behaviour was basically documented. In 1364-2005 this appears in 12.3.8 as

> A port that is declared as input (output) but used as an output (input) or inout may be coerced to inout. If not
>   coerced to inout, a warning has to be issued.

In practice, everything ends up as an `inout`, and you may or may not get a warning. So, you can do pretty much anything in a simulator, but a linter or a synthesiser should pick up any logical connection errors for you (if it doesn't, it's pretty useless). There are other specific non-direction rules in the following sections - `input` and `inout` ports have to be of `net` type, and so on.

Comment: This is not correct about SystemVerilog. Because of the rules for continuous assignments to variables as well as the `uwire` nettype, you must chose the correct direction or get a multiple driver error.

Answer (score 4):

There are differences in `output` and `inout` ports:

1. You can't read and write `inout` port simultaneously, hence kept `'Z` for reading.
2. `inout` port can **never** be of type `reg`. It must be of `wire` type.
3. There should be a signal which decides that whether the given port is an `input` or `output`.

In this module, you must have a `w_r` signal which functions as follows:

```
// w_r = 1 => output port
// w_r = 0 => input port
input w_r;    
inout cnt;    
reg write_cnt;    
reg read_cnt;    
// wire read_cnt;    
assign cnt = w_r ? write_cnt : 1'bz;    // driving logic for cnt

// inside some always block
read_cnt <= cnt;
write_cnt <= some_data;
```

Since the `inout` signal is wire, it must be driven by continuous assignment statements.

Referring to this part:

> So can inout and output ports be used interchangeably in Verilog?

The answer is that it is **not encouraged** to use them *interchangeably*. Since for output port, you can use `reg` type alone.

From synthesis point of view, the `inout` port can have **tri-state drivers or a Mux** as follows: (Note that this results can differ for synthesis tools which I am not sure about.):

[image: Bidirectional port assignment]

For more information refer to [Bidirectional port assignment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/how-to-assign-value-to-bidirectional-port-in-verilog) and [Bidirectional I/O Pins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33144/birectional-i-o-pin-in-verilog) forum question.

Comment: So it means, that indeed both can be used interchangeably (Though not recommended)? If no, then exactly what is the criteria, where inout port must be used? (Because as shown in above code, in "cnt" ideally inout port should be used, but it works fine with "output" port)

Comment: If you are going to use inout everywhere, then it will mess up with lots of extra hardware and control signals. In this code, cnt is not an inout, its just a reg or a group of flops. In the design, cnt  **holds** a value when start is not present and increments the **holded** value if start is present. So it might be used as **output** port only. As far as I have seen practically, while implementing some protocol like I2C(SDA I guess), inout port is required. There can be many other places of inout usage.

Answer (score 4):

Simulators don't care about port directions. Simulation tools always flatten out the module hierarchy and all that matters is that they can connect the two port signals together. They do not check that the flow of data is actually going in the specified direction. Unfortunately, what is required by the standard and what is implemented in a tool does not always match up.

Sometimes, a user will have code that "works" in one tool but not in another tool with stronger error checking. The user finds it is easier to make their tool vendor remove the error check than to have to go back and fix their code. Some most simulators have removed any checks to enforce port direction.

The rule about not declaring variables data types used inout ports remains mostly intact, but many tools allow constants to be connected to an inout port.

Comment: So port direction in the above code won't affect simulation, but can affect synthesis result(Means synthesis result of "output" cnt and "inout" cnt may differ)?

Comment: Probably would not compile in synthesis.

Comment: So now in above code, output port can be used, instead of inout. So can you give me any criteria, where inout port must be used?